# How to calculate columns totals dynamically in dx grid using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, devexpress

I have following dataset am binding to grid

```
EmpName     Basic       HRA     TA
Emp1        5000        500     600 
Emp2        8000        650     750 
Emp3        10000       800     875
    total   23000       1950        2150
```

I have decimal datatype for basic hra and ta 
without specifying column i want to calculate column totals based on datatype

```
   $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: EmpSalaries,
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Summary](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/summary/) configuration section where you can set summary type and columns whose value need to be summarized.

> To specify the items of the total summary, declare an array of
>   objects, each of which contains at least two fields: [column](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/summary/totalItems/#column) and
>   [summaryType](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/summary/totalItems/#summaryType). The column field specifies the identifier of the
>   column that provides data for an aggregate function. The **summaryType**
>   specifies the aggregate function to be applied. The following code
>   snippet shows how to declare two summary items.

See example here - [Grid Summaries](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/GridSummaries/AngularJS/Light/)

```
summary: {
            totalItems: [{
                column: "SaleAmount",
                summaryType: "sum"
            },
```

Hope this help..